# What is a `built-in type`

Tags: gcc, malloc, language-lawyer, memory-alignment, avx

> The malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any built-in type.

Now, GCC provides *built-in* support for vector types through the syntax[1]

```
template<class T>
using vec4_t __attribute__ ((vector_size (4*sizeof(T))))=T;
```

And it is possible to do arithmetic operations on two `vec4_t<float>`, or with AVX `vec4_t<double>` directly, yet `malloc` cannot be used on 32-bit platforms when `T`=`float`, or on 64-bit platforms when `T`=`double`.

Now [there is P0035R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0035r1.html), which sort of solves the problem of dynamic allocation for over-aligned types. But why is it not better to blame  `malloc` instead of adding more variants to `operator new`?[2] Indeed, the compiler has built-in support for these types, so one would expect `malloc` to work properly.

[1] In C, I would have to specify the type for each typedef

[2] Page-aligned memory is another issue

Comment: `__attribute__((vector_size))` is more like a facility for defining types (similar to the `struct` keyword, or arrays), not actually a type.  Also, it has unbounded size, so how is a library `malloc` function supposed to know what alignment a program requires?  You could write a program that used vectors with 4096 elements.  Or do you mean why doesn't malloc assume that the the maximum required alignment is 32B on systems with AVX support, ignoring any alignment specifier for the type?

Comment: @PeterCordes I mean the latter. Maybe I would go as far as the cache-line size, that is 64 bytes.

Comment: Obviously because most allocations don't need that, so it would be a waste of memory.  Spreading your program's data over more cache lines is worse for your cache footprint.

Comment: @PeterCordes Unless you have a situation of false sharing. I would also argue that many allocations are much larger than 64 B. Especially in context of SIMD, but also in other cases, like growing dynamic arrays of data (std::vector). Not in the case of trees and linked lists though.

Comment: Those are the exception, not the rule.  If one thread does multiple allocations, it's usually a good thing if they're in the same cache line.  Since NUMA is a possibility, you ideally want each thread to allocate its own memory, so a NUMA-aware allocator can do a better job.  A function doing multiple small allocations of objects that will be used by separate threads should be avoiding false sharing by something more reliable than hoping malloc doesn't return nearby memory from successive calls!

Comment: Large allocations usually end up page-aligned anyway, on malloc implementations like glibc that go to the OS for fresh pages for big allocations (and munmap them right away on free, instead of adding them to the free list and chopping them up).

Comment: Anyway, don't get me wrong, I think it's really dumb that `std::vector<__m128>` can segfault.  But what you're proposing doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: @PeterCordes: There is only one way to know: Run representative benchmarks with different malloc alignments. However, SSE code must be excluded since we want to compare with to small alignments for SSE.

Comment: Agreed.  That would be interesting to have benchmarks for a few different kinds of workloads, like Firefox or Chrome, SPECint, and IDK probably some other kinds of software too.